# virtual はなぜ「仮想」なんでしょうか

Tags: 英語

オイラの英語知識からいうと virtual という単語は
- 実質的に
- 事実上の
としか翻訳できないのですが、
コの業界ではなぜ「仮想」なる日本語が充てられているのでしょうか。

日本語で「仮想」だと
- 存在しない
- にせもの
のようにイメージされて、英語のニュアンスとまるっきり逆な気がします。

Comment: 同じ疑問を持っている方多数。[virtualを「仮想」と訳していいものか](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yaneurao/20100803#p1), [Virtualを仮想と誤訳した責任は我々にあります](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/oraccha/20140926/1411694081) 後者のリンクで出てくる恩師は僕の大学時代の恩師でもあります。

Answer (score 16, accepted):

日経ビジネスオンラインの[「言葉のインフレ」は経済のそれよりはるかに恐ろしい](http://business.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/tech/20100331/213753)という記事の3ページ目に次のような記述があります(要会員登録の記事なので要約のみ示します)

- 米IBMがvirtual memoryを発表した時、日本IBMのエンジニアが仮想記憶と訳した。
- それが広まって、virtualの定訳までも「仮想」になってしまった。
- 訳した当人はもっと良い訳語にしておけば良かったと悔やんでいる。

このエピソードの初出は日経コンピュータ2010年3月31日号のようです。

Comment: なんだか聞いたことがあるような気がします。結構最近の話なのですね。

Comment: 翻訳されたのはずいぶん前でしょうから、折に触れそういう話は出てたのだと思います。たまたま上のような記録が残ってたというだけで。

Answer (score 8):

英語版のWiktionaryにはこのように記述されています。
[virtual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/virtual)

> 1.In effect or essence, if not in fact or reality; imitated, simulated.
>   In fact a defeat on the battlefield, Tet was a virtual victory for the North, owing to its effect on public opinion.
>   Virtual addressing allows applications to believe that there is much more physical memory than actually exists.

英語でのvirtualには、記載されているように"if not in fact or reality"かつ"imitated, simulated"つまり『「事実」や「現実」ではないとしても』『模倣や模擬』のニュアンスが多分に含まれているようです。「実質的に」「事実上の」などの辞書上の訳語だけを見ずに、英英辞書などを引いて、その用例等を参考にされれば、「まるっきり逆」ではないことがわかるとおもいます。

Comment: オイラは「現実でないことを百も承知の上で、それでもあえて事実であるように扱う」肯定的なニュアンスで使う、と習いました。が言葉は変遷するものでもありますし、機会があったらネイティブスピーカーの人にも訊いてみます。

Comment: 「現実でない」ことを訳語にする時にさてどう表すかという、どちらかというと日本語の方に対する感覚の問題なのかもしれません。日本語で「事実上の」と言うと「法律上の(あるいはそれ以外の名目上の)」裏付けのない何か、という感覚なので、必ずしも肯定的かどうか疑問ですし、「仮想」に「にせもの」と言った否定的なイメージがあるかどうかも疑問です。とりあえず自分的には「誤訳」と断言してしまえるほどの差異は感じられないのですが、個人の感覚を回答に持ち込むのは不適当かと思い、リンクをつけさせていただきました。。興味深い話題ですので、何か新しい事実が見つかりましたら、お知らせいだければ嬉しい限りです。

Comment: 英語圏で18年暮らしていますけれど、日常会話の中で使う(コンピュータ関連でない)virtualは、「厳密に本当か？って言われたら断言できないけど、ほぼ間違いなく」です。例えば地球温暖化のニュースで"we're virtually certain that 2016 will be the warmest year on record"といえば「(今年はまだ終わっていないから断言はできないけど)ほぼ間違いなくもっとも暖かい年になると分かっている」という使い方です。imitated, simulatedの意味は二次的に発生したものでコンピュータの分野以外で聞いたことがないです。 コンピュータの分野で1960年代にvirtual Xと名付けた人は新発明に対して、既存の単語を新しい概念に当てたのでしょう。それでvirtualにimitated/simulatedの意味が発生したのであれば日本語の仮想に新しい意味が加わったのも自然な流れなのかもしれません。

Comment: 「断言はできないけど」の部分をどう表現するのかと言うことで、やはり日本語の方に対する感覚の問題という気はします。英語圏にお住まいなら情報は集めやすいかと思いますので、何か新しい情報が入りましたら、お聞かせ願えれば嬉しいです。ちなみにコンピュータの分野以外ですと、real image(実像)、virtual image(虚像)なんて使い方をする例がありますね。

Answer (score 1):

おっしゃるようにvirtualは「ほとんど〇〇と同じ（だけど同じじゃない」という文脈で使うのが普通ですね。virtually non existentと言えば「実質的に存在しない」というわけですね。

hypothetical enemy (仮説上の敵）は日本語に直すと仮想敵国で、仮に想定した敵国だとすれば、こちらはまだ意味が通ります。間違っても事実上の敵ではないわけです（いや、そう解釈するともっと面白いかもしれない。笑）このことからもvirtualを仮想と訳したのは誤りでしょう。

なぜこのような訳語が採用されたのかはわかりませんが、おそらく国語学者でもないエンジニアがメインフレームのマニュアルを訳した時に適当に当てただけの気がします！！

Answer (score 0):

「数値解析入門第２版」(サイエンス社、2003年)では微分方程式の数値解法であるvirtual point method を仮想分点法と訳しています。「仮想」という訳語は数値解析の分野でも使われているようです。